# MS Access join on wildcard

Tags: ms-access, join, wildcard

So I have two tables, tblMaster and Software.

I would like to join these tables with a wildcard join. My tables are formatted like so.

**tblMaster**

```
|ID|Title                           |type|state|
------------------------------------------------
|1 |Adobe Reader                    |A   |Close|
|2 |Apache HTTP Server              |A   |Close|
|3 |Multiple Mozilla Products       |A   |Open |
|4 |Microsoft Windows File Handling |A   |Open |
|5 |Microsoft Windows Client Server |A   |Open |
|6 |HP Printer                      |A   |Open |
|7 |Adobe Acrobat                   |A   |Close|
```

**Software**

```
|SWID|Software Title    |location|
----------------------------------
|1   |Adobe Reader      |1|
|2   |Apache            |1|
|3   |Mozilla           |1|
|4   |Microsoft Windows |2|
|5   |HP                |3|
```

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM Software
left Join tblMaster on Software.[Software Title] like "*" & tblMaster.Title & "*";
```

But when I do this I get this error:

Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object ( Software.[Software Title] like "*" & tblMaster.Title & "*").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't join on a wildcard, so this requires a bit of creativity:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Software
Left Join  (SELECT tblMaster.*, Software.[SWID] 
FROM tblMaster, Software 
WHERE [Software Title] LIKE "*" & tblMaster.Title & "*") 
AS A 
ON A.[SWID] = Software.[SWID]
```

This first links all possible joins, and then actually joins the fields.
It will report `[Software Title]` twice, adjust if this is a problem.

If you're OK with an inner join, you might be able to just use the subquery.

Comment: sorry it took so long to get back. I like your solution, but I'm still getting the `Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink (Software.[Software Title]=A.[Software Title])` error

Comment: Try the edited answer now. It joins on a different field, but it actually compares software title in the inner query (between the parentheses). If this doesn't work, please also post the table structure (types of each column, screenshot or written)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
    Software.* 
FROM 
    Software,
    tblMaster
WHERE
    Software.[Software Title] Like "*" & tblMaster.Title & "*";
```

Comment: That's an inner join, not a left join

Comment: True, but no fields from tblMaster are requested.

Comment: In the question, the selected column is a general wildcard, equal to `Software.*, tblMaster.*`, and even though no fields from tblMaster are requested, those from Software that aren't joined don't meet the where criterium.